# Access control origin header set in nginx.config file still get an error of Access control origin header allow

Tags: javascript, wordpress, nginx, webserver

```
http {
  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

  server {
      if ($request_method = 'POST') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
      }
      if ($request_method = 'GET') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
      }
  }
}
```

I hit the request from other server get the following error:

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin

The header is present on the requested resource. Origin http://localhost:3000 is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

Comment: [documentation for add_header](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#add_header) - `Adds the specified field to a response header provided that the response code equals 200, 201 (1.3.10), 204, 206, 301, 302, 303, 304, 307 (1.1.16, 1.0.13), or 308 (1.13.0). The value can contain variables` - so, 404 isn't in that list - why would you allow access to a non-existent resource?

Comment: What type of request is the application making? If `OPTIONS` you should return a `204` right after adding the headers.